# AngularJS Vertical table using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects, I want to build a table using ng-repeat that will insert data in the correct columns.

Right now I am doing it like this and I can't get it the correct way.

Please see [Plunker for more details](http://plnkr.co/edit/zh5FkqU6j7IWmj2Rj9EP?p=preview)

```
<div class container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
          <th>Time ()</th>
          <th>Room - One</th>
          <th>Room - Two</th>
          <th>Room - Three</th>
          <th>Room - Four</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="company in dataOne track by $index">
          <td>{{company.start}} - {{company.end}}</td>
          <td>{{company.company}}</td>
          <td>{{company.company}}</td>
          <td>{{company.company}}</td>
          <td>{{company.company}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample Data

```
        $scope.dataOne = [{

    "start": "7:30",
    "end": "8:00",
    "company": "Sony"
  }, {
    "start": "7:30",
    "end": "8:00",
    "company": "LG"
  }, {
    "start": "7:30",
    "end": "8:00",
    "company": "UPS"
  }, {
    "start": "7:30",
    "end": "8:00",
    "company": "MSI"
  }, {
    "start": "8:00",
    "end": "8:30",
    "company": "Samsung"
  }, {
    "start": "8:00",
    "end": "8:30",
    "company": "Tesco"
  }, {
    "start": "8:00",
    "end": "8:30",
    "company": "VW"
  }, {
    "start": "8:00",
    "end": "8:30",
    "company": "Audi"
  }, {
    "start": "9:00",
    "end": "9:30",
    "company": "BMW"
  }, {
    "start": "9:00",
    "end": "9:30",
    "company": "Sunoco"
  }, {
    "start": "9:00",
    "end": "9:30",
    "company": "Blizzard"
  }, {
    "start": "9:00",
    "end": "9:30",
    "company": "CS"
  }, {
    "start": "9:30",
    "end": "10:00",
    "company": "Mazda"
  }, {
    "start": "9:30",
    "end": "10:00",
    "company": "Nissan"
  }, {
    "start": "9:30",
    "end": "10:00",
    "company": "Porsche"
  }, {
    "start": "9:30",
    "end": "10:00",
    "company": "Hyundai"
  }]
  console.log($scope.dataOne)
```

Comment: What does your `$scope.dataOne` look like?

Comment: sample data is included in the plunker please take a look

Comment: you can use nested `ng-repeat` if data array is not too long

Comment: Each Time slot needs to have an array of meetings and than displayed

Comment: ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end?

Comment: Still looking for the best solution.. =/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to show a company only if it belongs to a room, this way you need to group companies in rooms

```
{
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "rooms":{
        3:{
          "company": "companyOne, Inc."
        }
      }
 }
```

You can see an working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ofmCLudxULNc49yN4Ya6?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for this but the data has over 50 objects for each day, I won't be able to change all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having same data in each row except timing you can make a copy of this array. If data array  is not too long then you can do it like this.

Make a copy of this array in `registrationCTRL.js`

```
 $scope.dataTwo = angular.copy($scope.dataOne);
```

and then iterate it like this

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
          <th>Time ()</th>
          <th>Room - One</th>
          <th>Room - Two</th>
          <th>Room - Three</th>
          <th>Room - Four</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="companyRow in dataOne track by $index">
          <td>{{::companyRow.start}} - {{::companyRow.end}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="companyCol in dataTwo track by $index">
            {{::companyCol.company}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CbDzPNGnGMnucHGlY6IY?p=preview)

Comment: This example creates more rows than needed, and repeats company horizontally instead of vertically . I think my problem is in my data structure  I will need to somehow split the array into 4 objects and then use ng-repeat. Thank you for help tho!

Answer (score 0):

> May be this is what you want:

Here I have to assume that you have only roomOne's data in that array.  Add data for the remaining three room into the same array (8 company in each).
Now you will have (no. of timeslots * no. of rooms) data in the array
do the ng-repeat for no. of timeslots times.

> first iteration prints 0-8 (8*$index to 8*($index+1)+8), $index = 0
>
> second iteration prints 9-16 (8*$index+1 to 8*($index+1)+8), $index = 1
>
> third iteration prints 17-24 (8*$index+1 to 8*($index+1)+8), $index = 2
>
> Fourth iteration prints 25-32 (8*$index+1 to 8*($index+1)+8), $index = 3
>
> JS

```
(function() {
"use strict";

 angular
.module("app")
.controller("registrationCTRL", function($scope) {

  $scope.dataOne = [{

      "start": "7:50",
      "end": "8:25",
      "company": "companyOne, Inc. in room-1"
    }, {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyTwo, Inc. in room-1"
    },

    {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyThree, Inc. in room-1"
    }, {
      "start": "9:00",
      "end": "9:25",
      "company": "companyFour, Inc. in room-1"
    },

    {
      "start": "9:25",
      "end": "10:00",
      "company": "companyFive, Inc. in room-1"
    }, {
      "start": "10:00",
      "end": "10:25",
      "company": "companySix, Inc. in room-1"
    },

    {
      "start": "10:25",
      "end": "11:00",
      "company": "companySeven, Inc. in room-1"
    }, {
      "start": "11:00",
      "end": "11:25",
      "company": "companyEight, Inc. in room-1"
    },
    {

      "start": "7:50",
      "end": "8:25",
      "company": "companyNine, Inc. in room-2"
    }, {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyTen, Inc. in room-2"
    },

    {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyEleven, Inc. in room-2"
    }, {
      "start": "9:00",
      "end": "9:25",
      "company": "companyTwelve, Inc. in room-2"
    },

    {
      "start": "9:25",
      "end": "10:00",
      "company": "companyThirteen, Inc. in room-2"
    }, {
      "start": "10:00",
      "end": "10:25",
      "company": "companyFourteen, Inc. in room-2"
    },

    {
      "start": "10:25",
      "end": "11:00",
      "company": "companyFifteen, Inc. in room-2"
    }, {
      "start": "11:00",
      "end": "11:25",
      "company": "companySixteen, Inc. in room-2"
    },
    {

      "start": "7:50",
      "end": "8:25",
      "company": "companySeventeen, Inc. in room-3"
    }, {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyEighteen, Inc. in room-3"
    },

    {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyNineteen, Inc. in room-3"
    }, {
      "start": "9:00",
      "end": "9:25",
      "company": "companyTwenty, Inc. in room-3"
    },

    {
      "start": "9:25",
      "end": "10:00",
      "company": "companyTwentyOne, Inc. in room-3"
    }, {
      "start": "10:00",
      "end": "10:25",
      "company": "companyTwentyTwo, Inc. in room-3"
    },

    {
      "start": "10:25",
      "end": "11:00",
      "company": "companyTwentyThree, Inc. in room-3"
    }, {
      "start": "11:00",
      "end": "11:25",
      "company": "companyTwentyFour, Inc. in room-3"
    },
    {

      "start": "7:50",
      "end": "8:25",
      "company": "companyTwentyfive, Inc. in room-4"
    }, {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyTwentySix, Inc. in room-4"
    },

    {
      "start": "8:25",
      "end": "9:00",
      "company": "companyTwentySeven, Inc. in room-4"
    }, {
      "start": "9:00",
      "end": "9:25",
      "company": "companyTwentyEight, Inc. in room-4"
    },

    {
      "start": "9:25",
      "end": "10:00",
      "company": "companyTwentyNine, Inc. in room-4"
    }, {
      "start": "10:00",
      "end": "10:25",
      "company": "companyThirty, Inc. in room-4"
    },

    {
      "start": "10:25",
      "end": "11:00",
      "company": "companyThirtyOne, Inc. in room-4"
    }, {
      "start": "11:00",
      "end": "11:25",
      "company": "companyThirtyTwo, Inc. in room-4"
    }
  ];


  function getRooms(){
     return 4;
  }

  $scope.getTimeslots = function(num) {
    return new Array(num/getRooms());   
  }


});
})();
```

> HTML

```
    <tr ng-repeat="i in getTimeslots(dataOne.length) track by $index">
        <td>{{dataOne[$index].start}}-{{dataOne[$index].end}}</td>
        <td>{{dataOne[$index+0*8].company}}</td>
        <td>{{dataOne[$index+1*8].company}}</td>
        <td>{{dataOne[$index+2*8].company}}</td>
        <td>{{dataOne[$index+3*8].company}}</td>
    </tr>
```

> Working Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/h0AGmG?p=preview

Comment: What if I have an array that its length it not divisible by the room number.

Comment: Ex: Array[50] / 4 = 12.5  it will throw an "error Invalid array length" how would I handle that? Otherwise this is great thank you.

Comment: You can compute that based on the actual data you get.  I assumed that no. of time slots are always the same (same durations) and the number of rooms are always 4.  If you have asymmetric (because you think it is real-time), then either you have to do that calculation on the UI or you can nicely ask backend to make that simpler for you.  Either way it is data that can figured out, at least if the same start time repeats on the day, I can say room-2 started right.

Comment: And also if I have more or less companies presenting '<td>{{dataOne[$index+0*8].company}}</td>' it won't handle it correctly.

Comment: go for a multi-dimensional array.  When you use iterate, then you are iterating over integers.  There is no room for decimal figures there.